# PHP access settings.xml file outside of http root

Tags: php, apache

I have a settings.xml file that I need to access from my PHP code that sits outside of the `WWW` root in a folder on my Linux server.

e.g

```
/var/websites/website.com/wwwroot/index.php
```

needs to access a file at

```
/var/settings folder/settings.xml
```

I tried this

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file(dirname(__FILE__) . '/var/settings folder/settings.xml')
or die("Error: Cannot create object");
```

The file has confidential information that I don't want anyone else to see - so don't want to add it to the Apache server as a virtual host, where anyone could find and browse the file.

Longer term, I plan to encrypt/decrypt it as well, in case the server is ever breached by SFTP etc

Looking on here, I found examples, but the above code will not load - I think I need to change permissions on apache? (or something else to allow PHP to access outside the apache URL root).

Thanks

Comment: just use the absolute path. No need to concatenate the current path. Remove the `dirname(__ FILE __). bit.

Comment: Permissions are unlikely to be a problem, unless you need to write to that file as well

Comment: Also, there is a problem with the `or die()` clause. Since you are putting a semicolon before the or, is going to `die()` everytime. :(

Comment: Well spotted :-) fixed that but still have the problem.  Also checked and the file has 0777 (i know this is bad - just wanted to make sure not a silly permission thing) and group of devuser:apache which is the same the other folders, it was missing apache group.  Seems to have made no difference :-(